# Access application from server on client machine by its name from any browser

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2012

I have installed application & database on same server. I can access the application on my client/local machine by "server IP". But I want to access same application on my client/local machine by "server name" and not by server IP.

How can I use the name instead of the IP?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get your server's IP into DNS. If this is on your local network, you have an internal DNS server most likely - you'd add a host record pointing from the name you want to the IP of the server.

Another option, if you only care about *this one particular machine* using the name, is to use the hosts file. Open `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, and add a mapping as described in the file:

`192.168.100.1   someserver`

..after which you can access the server with the name "someserver".